# Cast auto_ptr<Base> to auto_ptr<Derived>

Tags: c++, casting, auto-ptr

Please help me to understand the following issue.

Look at the code example below:

```
#include <iostream>

class Shape {
public:
  virtual wchar_t *GetName() { return L"Shape"; }
};
class Circle: public Shape {
public:
  wchar_t *GetName() { return L"Circle"; }
  double GetRadius() { return 100.; }
};

int wmain() {
  using namespace std;

  auto_ptr<Shape> aS;
  auto_ptr<Circle> aC(new Circle);

  aS = aC;
  wcout << aS->GetName() << L'\t' << static_cast<auto_ptr<Circle>>(aS)->GetRadius() << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Why I am not allowed to do this:

```
static_cast<auto_ptr<Circle>>(aS)->GetRadius()
```

Compiler (MSVCPP 11):

```
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xmemory(911): error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'Shape *' to 'Circle *'
1>          Cast from base to derived requires dynamic_cast or static_cast
```

Comment: @Truncheon: Are deliberately _trolling_? After months I haven't felt like this, your comment is another case of "I wish we could downvote comments!"

Comment: Too bad you cannot down-vote comments.. I agree with you on the fact that std::auto_ptrs aren't always the best alternative to use, though if memory management can be handled by an object wrapping the pointer I see nothing wrong with that. The developer might then focus on the real problem he is solving, instead of having to think about dangling pointers and such.

Comment: @sbi we think alike.. (note, I didn't see your comment when writing mine since I didn't refresh this thread)

Comment: @Truncheon: thanks for typing but I've asked what I've asked for.

Comment: Guys, there's new problem. There are 2 answers (Steve Jessop and refp). They both are correct, competent and constructive. How should I choose the "Correct answer" ?

Comment: @DaddyM: you could choose on the basis of either (1) reward the person whose answer was most helpful to you, or (2) highlight (and reward) the answer that you think will be most useful to people in the future who find this question by search.

Comment: Guys, I choose Steve Jessop's answer as the correct one. Really he wrote a book chapter that is very concise and comprehensive. Thank you all!!

Comment: `std::auto_ptr<>` is deprecated, don't use it anymore.

Comment: Thanks. But this question is all about auto_ptr.

Comment: @DaddyM: Yup. And comments are posts that are not answers. Knowing that auto_ptr is ought to be removed from the standard is good, however.

Comment: @phresnel Excuse me, I didn't understand what you've meant. Have I done something incorrect?

Comment: @DaddyM: No you havent't ;) But if you're writing programs that will stay for a longer time, then it is better to not use auto_ptr anymore. The next revision of the C++ standard will probably remove it (which is why it is declared deprecated now)

Comment: @phresnel Ok. I know.I've thought I've probably violated some forum rules. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`auto_ptr` doesn't behave the same way as a pointer in this respect. There are special rules in the language to allow `Shape*` to be static_cast to `Circle*` when `Circle` derives from `Shape`. The downcast is not entirely type-safe, since it relies on the user to provide a pointer value that actually does point to the `Shape` base class sub-object of a `Circle`, but the standard allows it for convenience. `auto_ptr` is "just" a library class, and has no equivalent conversion.

Even if you could do it, it would often go wrong. When you copy an `auto_ptr`, the original loses ownership of the resource. Your `static_cast` would copy the `auto_ptr` to a temporary, and so `aS` would be reset and the resource would be destroyed when the temporary is (at the end of the expression). In your example that's fine, since it's going to be destroyed at `return` anyway, but generally speaking you don't want to copy `auto_ptr` except at a function call parameter or return value, to indicate transfer of ownership from caller to callee, or vice versa.

What you can do instead is `static_cast<Circle*>(aS.get())->GetRadius()`, or better yet restructure your code to avoid the need for a downcast. If you know that your object is a `Circle`, keep it in an `auto_ptr<Circle>`[*]. If you keep it in an `auto_ptr<Shape>`, then don't rely on it being a `Circle`.

[*] Or, if your implementation provides them, a better smart pointer such as `unique_ptr`, `scoped_ptr` or `shared_ptr`. Even if your implementation doesn't provide them, there's Boost.

Comment: Very clear. Thanks. But what shall I do if I want to cast (static_cast) base to derived when using auto_ptr? I know that it can be erroneous but in this situation I know that pointer to base class object really points to the derived one.

Comment: I produced exactly the same code as refp's answer without seeing it, so it's probably right :-)

Comment: Dear readers, please refer to the refp answer (below) in order to see cast to reference example.

Comment: There is new question closely connected to Steve's answer: [static_cast and temporary creation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8581284/static-cast-and-temporary-creation)

Answer (score 3):

You certainly don't wanna do that cast, since `std::auto_ptr<T>` takes ownership of the internal pointer when initialized with another instance of the class.

`aS` will therefore loose the pointer and your `new Circle` object will be destroyed at the end of the `std::cout` statement, since the object-pointer is now owned by a temporary.

Instead you are probably looking for something like the below:

```
cout << ... << static_cast<Circle*>(aS.get ())->GetRadius() << endl;
```

You may also cast it to a reference, as below:

```
cout << ... << static_cast<Circle&> (*aS).GetRadius () << endl;
```