# static_cast and temporary creation (final edition)

Tags: c++, casting, static-cast, temporary-objects

**Prerequisities:**
To understand this question, please, read the following question and its answer at first:
[Cast auto_ptr<Base> to auto_ptr<Derived>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8574022/cast-auto-ptrbase-to-auto-ptrderived/8574098#8574098)

At
[Cast auto_ptr<Base> to auto_ptr<Derived>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8574022/cast-auto-ptrbase-to-auto-ptrderived/8574098#8574098) Steve answered that **"Your static_cast would copy the auto_ptr to a temporary, and so aS would be reset and the resource would be destroyed when the temporary is (at the end of the statement)."**

I'm interested in the process of temporary creation while `static_cast` is called.
I would like to have the code that I can trace in order to see this effect.
I cannot use `static_cast<auto_ptr<Circle>> ...` because it cannot be compiled, so I need to write some simulation class instead of `auto_ptr` and watch the process of temporary creation.

I also understand that temporary creation is closely connected with copy constructor call.
`auto_ptr`'s ownership loosing is simulated with copy assignment that set the `_radius` field of source to negative value (I need the simple logical model of `auto_ptr`).

So, I suggest the following `Circle` class:

```
#include <iostream>

class Shape {};

class Circle: public Shape {
  double _radius;
public:
  explicit Circle(double radius = .5): _radius(radius) {}
  Circle &operator =(Circle &circle) {
    _radius = circle._radius;
    circle._radius = -1.;
    return *this;
  }
  Circle(Circle &circle) { *this = circle; }
  double GetRadius() { return _radius; }
};

int wmain() {
  using namespace std;

  Circle c1(100), c2(200), c3(300);
  c2 = c3;

  Shape *s1, s2;
  s1 = &c1;
  wcout << static_cast<Circle *>(s1)->GetRadius() << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Ok. Here we can see that "ownership transferring" is taking place in `c2 = c3`.
BUT I cannot achieve temporary creation in `static_cast`.

The question is: how to make a small simulation of temporary object creation while `static_cast`?

I believe Steve that temporary object is created while casting. The only thing I want is **to write an example that shows temporary creation**. This target has academic reasons.

Can someone clarify how to achieve the effect described in Steve's answer that he posted at the referred topic?

Comment: Your description makes reference to `auto_ptr`... which is not used at all in your sample code. Could you clarify?

Comment: `int wmain()` is not a standard c++ main function.

Comment: @wilhelmtell I've edited the question. Please, re-read if you're interested in it.

Comment: "_operator should be called for that)._" which operator?

Comment: "`s1 = static_cast<Shape *>(&c2)`" why not just `s1 = &c2;`?

Comment: So, your question really is: when is `operator=` called implicitly?

Comment: @curiousguy No. :) I see I have to reformulate initial question. Just a minute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your previous question, `auto_ptr` is the class that has ownership, and resets the source's pointer to null when it is copied.

Now, `Circle` is a class that simulates ownership, by resetting its radius to -1 when it is copied. So it's like an `auto_ptr` in that way, but not in any other way.

So, to observe loss of simulated ownership you need to copy a `Circle`, which is what you do with copy assignment in the line `c2 = c3`. Casting a `Circle*` doesn't copy the object, just the pointer, but casting a `Circle` does copy the object:

```
int main() {
    Circle c1(100);
    static_cast<Circle>(c1);
    std::cout << c1.GetRadius() << '\n';
}
```

Output is -1.

Or if you specifically want to see it with a cast to a derived class:

```
struct SpecialCircle: Circle {
    SpecialCircle(Circle &circle) : Circle(circle) {}
    explicit SpecialCircle(double radius = .5): Circle(radius) {}
};

int main() {
    SpecialCircle s1(100);
    Circle &c1 = s1;
    static_cast<SpecialCircle>(c1);
    std::cout << c1.GetRadius() << '\n';
}
```

Comment: YEEESS!! Thanks. Steve, I'm looking forward to ask for your help in my later issues. Thanks all, guys. Here is what I need to hear.

Comment: @daddyM:. The problem with your code was you were making a temporary _pointer_, not a temporary cicle.

Comment: @MooingDuck Yep. I've understood this fact and got stack with how to implement non-pointer casting to call overloaded operators.

Answer (score 1):

> Ok. Here we can see that "ownership transferring" is taking place in c2 = c3. BUT I cannot achieve temporary creation in `static_cast`.

```
static_cast<Circle> (c2);
```

will "steal" from `c2`.

Answer (score 0):

You're fine with the `auto_ptr`. As [Steve's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8574098/721269) explains, the language is smart enough to do this with ordinary pointers. Casting a pointer between base and derived classes can require changing the value of the pointer, and a `static_cast` will do that when needed.

Comment: Ok. I wonder how to simulate the situation when temporary `auto_ptr` object is created. In my humble simulation `operator =` never called. Of course it's not practical question. It's theoretical investigation only. Again, I'm stuck with simulating `auto_ptr` temporary creation and copy assignment operator call. As you can see `Circle` class is rough simulation of loosing ownership in `auto_ptr`.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: Please, re-read question body. I've added some details. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The simplest I could think of is this (if you change the example in [your original question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8574022/476681)) :

```
wcout << aS->GetName() << L'\t' << static_cast<auto_ptr<Circle>>(aS.get())->GetRadius() << endl;
```

This :

```
static_cast<auto_ptr<Circle>>(aS.get())
```

creates a temporary of type `auto_ptr< Circle >`, which destructs the object of type `auto_ptr< Shape >` at the end of the scope.

Here is an example (I hope it is clear enough) :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

struct B
{
    ~B()
    {
        std::cout<<"~B"<<std::endl;
    }
    void foo()
    {
        std::cout<<"foo"<<std::endl;
    }
};
struct A : B
{
    ~A()
    {
        std::cout<<"~A"<<std::endl;
    }
    void bar()
    {
        std::cout<<"boom"<<std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    std::auto_ptr< A > a( new A );
    {
        std::auto_ptr< B > b( a.get() );
        b->foo();
    }

    std::cout<<"prepare for the crash"<<std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Right! That's Steve wrote in the answer to my original question. I cannot compile the code above (with `auto_ptr`). So, I would like to simulate such situation to track this temporary object creation. `Circle` class is in place of `auto_ptr`. I would like to make `operator =` run while creating temporary during `static_cast' call. Could you help me to write proper simulation code?

Comment: @DaddyM I added another example of what happens, but without a temporary object.

Comment: @DaddyM: `operator=` isn't used when copying in a cast, rather the copy constructor is. So there's no way to do what you seem to want, which is to have the `static_cast` result in a call to `operator=`.

Comment: @VJovic Thanks. But it is not what I'm interested in. You showed how `a` will try to call stored object destructor that is already destroyed by `b`. I'm interested in simulate this: `static_cast<auto_ptr<Circle>>(aS.get())` but with another UDF class (original code with `auto_ptr` will not work).

Comment: @SteveJessop Nice to see u here. You've understood me. Please, tell how to simulate such situation with UDF class that simulates 'loosing ownership' while copying to the temporary `static_cast`. All I'm wonder in: to trace calls to copy ctor while temporary creating in `static_cast`.